# Does javascript have a timer function?

Tags: javascript, timer, dojo, intervals

To explain the question. I have a dojo toolkit code which polls an open-monica server every 1 second to display the value on screen. I am trying to make an alarm which checks the values every 40 and 60 seconds. Therefore I am wondering if there is a function which can run alongside the passive polling of the dojo toolkit. I have tried setInterval() and setTimeout() however both of those stops the polling of the monica server

My code is:

```
require(["dojo/dom-attr", "atnf/monica", "dojo/domReady!"], function(domAttr, monica) {

function valCheck(){

}
    // The callback is called separately for each point
    // that has new data, so we only need to accept the reference to that
    // point as an argument.
    var pageUpdate = function(pointReference) {
        var values = pointReference.latestValue(); //obtain the updated values

        domAttr.set("htmlPageDiv", "innerHTML", values.value); //display the moniva value in their corresponding div in the html page
        }
    };

    // We set up the connection to the MoniCA server.
    var monicaServer = monica.server({
        'webserverName': "some server",
        'serverName': "serverName",
        "webserverPath": "webServerPath",
        'updateInterval': 1000, // in ms
        'autoDescriptions': true
    });

    // Connect to it now, and when that is done, tell it which
    // points we want to query.
    monicaServer.connect().then(function(serverObj) {

        //add monica points to check in the server
        var points = monicaServer.addPoints(["some data point", "another data point", "etc."]);
        // Tell the server connector which function to call on each
        // update, for each point (we use the same callback for each.
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            points[i].addCallback(pageUpdate);
        }
        // Get the descriptions and then start updating.
        monicaServer.getDescriptions();
        monicaServer.startUpdating();
    });
});
```

Comment: What other kind of timer function are you looking for than `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?

Comment: `setInterval` doesn't stop unless you make it stop *(or close the page)*. By calling `clearInterval` with the id that `setInterval` returns. So why don't you show the code where you tried the polling?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that whatever code you're running with `setInterval` is interfering with Dojo. Maybe you need to find out if Dojo has a function to do what you want.

Comment: Try this: `setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);`